# Programmatic database structure rollout

Tags: .net, relational-database

I would like to have a definition for my datamodel and let my application check and sync it at startup.

Unfortunately I cannot find any product out there doing this so I like to hear if you know one or if you have recommendations how to solve this problem.

The solution I think of: The application reads the definition (an XML file for example) at startup and compares with the DB structure. If it is different it generates `ALTER TABLE` statements and adopts. It might also create default records in some tables if they are missing. And it should support multiple RDBMS (ms sql, oracle, db2, etc.) and run in .NET.

Doing this with hundreds of SQL scripts and rollback-scripts seem kind of unpractical and error-prone to me.

I can start programming this by myself but maybe there is something out there which is quite pretty?

Comment: Your database definition should be either defined and created by the source code (As in EF Code First), or versioned together with the source code. Look at tools like http://www.liquibase.org/ for example.

Comment: I agree with versioning it together with the source code. You could take advantage of an O/RM like @AndersForsgren has suggested as well.  Another simple approach may be to store the data structure version somewhere, and write patches between versions. This way, your program can apply all patches necessary to bring a given DB up to date.

Comment: Liquibase is quite near to the thing I am searching for. But it is not yet available in .NET to be called directly from my app. But I will think about calling it from command line.

The problem with EF is that I am only on .NET2 here and I do not know any ORM solution which solves this problem there.

I like the Liquibase solution because the XML files can be added to the same VCS as the source code.